# Need to Pause VBA Script While Links Update

Tags: excel, vba, wait, pause, doevents

The core problem appears to be in the sub procedure. For simplicity I placed this in the main procedure:
The problem I am facing is in the following code:

`Sub US_Sub01()`

`Dim NAtotal As Integer`

`NAtotal = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(20, "C").Value`

`MsgBox(“NAtotal”)` 'This shows me how many remaining links need to be updated. Starts at 4540.

`Do Until NAtotal = 0`  'This loop should keep going until NAtotal hits zero.

`NAtotal = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(20, "C").Value`

`DoEvents`

`Loop`

`NAtotal` does not change from 4540 and never counts down. If I break the macro cell C20 immediately updates to zero.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Steve

Comment: Is C20 empty initially? Can you introduce a loop until C20 = 0 (truly = 0)

Comment: No. C20 is the sum of cells C5:C19. These cells count all instances of #N/A from other tabs. The Application.CalculateFull forces C5:C19 to contain #N/A which is then updated in C20. Depending on the Sub spreadsheet, this value varies from 200 to 15,000.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call the functions to calculate formulas and update links as follows:

Update formulas: `Application.Calculate`

Update Links: `ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink`

If you want a status update for this process you will need to loop through each cell in the workbook and use code like this for each cell:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Calculate
```

Then set `Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(20, "C").Value = total cells - loop count` but I think this will slow your code down too much to be useful but let me know if you want this and I can create the code.

If you want something to tell the user that the sheet is being updated you can do something like this:

```
Excel.Application.StatusBar = "Updating Links & Formulas"
'Changes the "Ready in the status bar to what you want it to say
Application.Calculate 'Calculate Formulas
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink 'Update Links
Excel.Application.StatusBar = False 'Changes back to "Ready" status
```

Just adding a `:Do Events` onto the end of your `Set ActiveWKB = Workbooks.Open("Sub01.xlsm")` might work too.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad: Thank you for your suggestions, but these did not give me the solution.

Comment: Steve - Credit, where credit is due, this is actually @Zamokak 's answer, I just edited it to fix a formatting issue. If it does not work for you, please consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53785019/edit) to give us more info. e.g. what is the new behaviour when you try this solution?

Comment: Sorry, Newbie here just trying to get used to the formatting. I'll edit the question.